# iOS : Can multiple person share one apple individual development account?

Tags: ios, account

I'm a hobbyist of iOS development. I have another **3 overseas friends** to work with me on one app. Now I want to open a development account to debug ,test our app. after that release to 
App Store.

so Now I want to know , **could we just open one individual development account and share among us on respective iPhone ?** because we haven't registered a company , no choice to apply a company one . 
**is it convenient for us to share one individual development account ?**

**if sharing one individual account among us is not a good idea. then what's the right or best way for my situation ?**

thanks.

Comment: What the heck's stopping you from just doing it now?  How's apple ever your to figure out that three people are behind one account out of millions?

Answer (score 5):

This would be against Apple's Guidelines (looking for citation), but it's possible- however, the main concern would be the fact that you would all have to share certificates, including the person-who-registered-the-account's private key. So while it's possible, it'll be difficult and overcomplicated- plus someone's private key certificate will be floating around, and that's never fun.

**EDIT:** [This page](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enrollment.html), under "Which iOS Developer Program should I join?", says:

> Join as an individual if you are a sole proprietor or if you develop under your own name.

So if you're the complete owner of the account (and as such, the apps it produces), **or** if you "develop under your own name" (interpret that how you will!), then it'll be valid under Apple's ToS; still difficult, but valid.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest route in the long run might be to go ahead and form a single member LLC (assuming you're in the USA). Then you can contact Apple to convert your individual developer program to a company program. The cost of the program is the same. Once you have a company program, you can add multiple developers to your team, allowing them to build and debug the app on iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can register as an individual for now. Then, if you want to incorporate into a company, you can.

Comment: Care to elaborate and provide evidence in the body of your answer?